# Inferred parameter types in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

The following code generates type mismatch error. I dont't understand why.

```
var navigablemap=rst.getFamilyMap("a".getBytes())
var list = new ListBuffer[Long]()
navigablemap.keySet().forEach((e:Array[Byte]) => list+=Bytes.toLong(e))
```

*navigablemap* has the type *NavigableMap[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]*. 
One would expect *e* to have the type *Array[Byte]*

Compiler reports the following error message.

*type mismatch; found : Array[Byte] ⇒ list.type (with underlying type Array[Byte] ⇒ list.type) required: java.util.function.Consumer[_ >: Array[Byte]]*

Update: The following works.

```
var keys=navigablemap.keySet()
var keysIterator=keys.iterator()
while (keysIterator.hasNext){ 
  var e=keysIterator.next()
  list+=Bytes.toLong(e)
}
```

Since brevity is one of my goals while I try to learn scala, is  there a scala-one-liner for the above ?

Comment: What do you think `(e:Array[Byte])` is doing? (and so it's not about inferred parameter types but explicit ones)

Comment: aren't you using java api in scala? you can't simply pass scala lambda where java lambda is required.

Comment: Why does the compiler think that the type is not `Array[Byte]` ? The inferred type is different from the expected (and specified) type.

Comment: @Łukasz Could you please be specific ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a stupid mistake. As Lukasz commented on the question, scala lambdas cannot replace java lambda. For future references, this is the working solution.

```
var navigablemap=rst.getFamilyMap("a".getBytes())
val list = new ListBuffer[Long]()
var keys=navigablemap.keySet()
val scalaKeys=asScalaSet(keys)
scalaKeys.foreach(x => list+=Bytes.toLong(x))
```

The conversion `asScalaSet` is important.